# Connect PHP login with Laravel APP with its own login

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have done a software using Laravel 5.4 and it has a login system. This software is a submodule for another app developed with PHP with its own login system.

What I want to do is to, somehow, bypass my Laravel app to automatically login once the user has logged in the main PHP app. Using the same MySQL database, of course.

Maybe that's a bad idea and I should ¿delete? my Laravel login. I am missing ideas.

How is the best/easy way to do this? Any tip?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which table you are using for login with the other system.   you could login with Auth::login($user); Have  a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users. Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look. The table to login is the same BUT the php login works with user/password and my login works with email/password.

Answer (score 1):

```
Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]); 
    if ( Auth::check() ) {
    // redirect to after login.
    }
```

Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This should work but another problem I have is that the hash or encryption is different in the apps. How can I manage it to work?

Comment: Authenticating Users By ID

To log a user into the application by their ID, use the loginUsingId method:

Auth::loginUsingId(1); // use the primary of the table.